# Spreadsheet formula to sum values from last 3 months

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't find any formula which matches what I 'm lokking for and mine doesnt work...

I have data like this :

```
date         | value
12/12/2020       0
10/11/2020       1
```

And I need to show in 1 cell the sum of Value column where the Date is from the last three month.

I've tried with this :

```
=SUM.IF(G3:G;MONTH(A3)>=MONTH(TODAY())-3;A3:A)
```

But it gives 0 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of **SUMIF** is incorrect due to the ff reasons:

- First parameter should be the range of the data to be used as comparison on the Second parameter.
- You cannot include a standalone condition in the second parameter since the comparison should be between the first parameter and another value which you will specify in the second parameter.
- Third parameter should be the range of the value you wanted to sum up. In this case, I think you should use G3:G.

With this, please refer to the formula below to solve your problems. I used *EDATE* to calculate the date 3 months before. You can opt not to do it the exact same way.

```
=SUMIF(A3:A, ">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-3), G3:G)
```

I tried this on your data set and it is working perfectly.